# How to fixed USB Pen Drive not showing in file manager?

Tags: usb-drive, 22.04, filemanager

I try resetting(flash) my USB Pen Drive but while the flash(reset) was in progress I mistakenly cancelled the process. Then my USB Drive stopped showing up in the file manager but when I checked from the terminal it's listed. How can I fixed this?

This is the command I used
`lsusb`

Comment: Use Disks to format it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how sir? I am a beginner.

Comment: Disks is an app/tool like any other. Search it like any other and click to open.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks Sir! I just formated it and it register.